# Location of SQL Expression Editor

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports doesn't seem to have a SQL Expression Editor. I know the Editor is only available when I select tables from source, so how can I add my own SQL Expression  to my report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write your own SQL expression within Crystal, go to the *Field Explorer* on the right side of the Design view. Right click *Database Fields* and select *Database Expert.*

Pick the matching connection you want to use, and select *Add Command*

[image]

From here on out, Crystal will treat your statement as if it was another existing table.